# Is there a way to put a condition to what activity is going to be my main activity?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I'm creating a simple android application to show a website inside the app using WebView. My main activity page asks the user to put the URL of the website and saves it. My next activity is a login page. My plan is to make the login page as the main activity once the user entered a URL so next time they open the app they just need to login.

I did some research and find out that I can go to `AndroidManifest` to change which activity I want to launch first. but I want the user to put their URL first before changing it. So my question is, is there a way I can put a condition like if statement that checks if URL has data in it, the login page will be launch first?

Answer (score 2):

Create a translucent (or a regular splash if you want) activity which will always be your first activity (launcher activity). This activity will either launch your main activity or login activity depending on whatever condition you code. This way, in your scenario, when launcher activity starts, it will check if url is entered and if it is, it will launch login activity. Else main activity will launch where user can enter url.